# the docker client must be run elevated to connect (can´t start docker on Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v, docker, docker-for-windows

I can´t start docker on my Windows 10. I have checked all suggestions found around.

- My Laptop Dell has Virtualization enabled in BIOS
- Hyper V is enabled
  [image]
- I have unistalled and resintalled both manually and through Chocolatey
- I can see the version so I assume all system variables are done (I ran the PowerShell as administrator)

[image]

- I followed https://success.docker.com/article/docker-for-windows-fails-with-a-daemon-not-running-message by restarting Docker service
- I quited Citrix Receiver

In case it adds some relevant info, I get an error when I try to connect straigh from Hyper-V -> Action -> Connect to Server

[image]

PS.: This question was originally asked in https://serverfault.com/questions/957207/how-enable-virtualization-in-windows-10-pro-in-order-to-use-docker but put on hold

Comment: Please do not submit the same question to multiple communities.  So the error indicates, you must run Docker with elevated permissions, have you done that?  In the future, if a question is closed, have the question be migrated, by a moderator to the proper community.  Please provide an English translation to all error messages.

Comment: @Ramhound, I think it's fair to ask this here in this instance since the question was placed on hold for being off-topic and better suited for this community given that "...Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User..." as reads the close reason on Serverfault.

Comment: "you must run Docker with elevated permissions". Does my above original comment "I ran the PowerShell as administrator" answer your question?